# iOS VoIP push notifications and Firebase

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, voip

I'm trying to send VoIP push notifications through the Firebase. I uploaded a *.p8 file to my project in the Firebase Console and now have an **APNs Auth Key** displayed there.

My alarm push notifications are delivered without any problems:

```
'apns' => [
    'headers' => [
        'apns-push-type' => ‘alarm',
    ],
...
```

But when I try to change the type to `voip` I get an error:

```
'apns' => [
    'headers' => [
        'apns-push-type' => 'voip',
        'apns-topic' => ‘com.mycompany.myapp.voip'
    ],
...
```

Firebase response:

```
#errors: array:1 [
      "error" => array:4 [
        "code" => 400
        "message" => "Request contains an invalid argument."
        "status" => "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
        "details" => array:2 [
          0 => array:2 [
            "@type" => "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError"
            "errorCode" => "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
          ]
          1 => array:2 [
            "@type" => "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest"
            "fieldViolations" => array:1 [
              0 => array:2 [
                "field" => "message.token"
                "description" => "Invalid registration token"
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Any ideas? Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 3):

The situation at the date (16/03/2020): **No, Firebase Cloud Messaging doesn't support APNS VoIP push notifications**, but it's planned.

The official Firebase support answer:

> Currently, VoIP push is not supported by FCM. However, we're aware that a lot of developers like you want this, so there's already a feature request filed for this. As of now, we are yet to find out any details or timelines as to when it will be implemented. You can check our [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases) from time to time for any updates about Firebase features and its services.

Comment: Any changes on this one @Mac? Is it supported now? (September 2020)

Comment: I had to work with APNS directly without Firebase, so I'm not aware of any updates on this. But a quick look at the Firebase release notes doesn't give any results.

Comment: Is there a tutorial how to use APNS directly? Thanks a lot

Comment: Apple documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns/

Comment: Any updates on this, I'm facing the same issue.